# Attempting to create chart based on activity over a 24 hour period

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

Apologies in advance if I say something that does not make sense. I have been trying to teach myself Python through Udemy courses, so I am not the most knowledgeable.

I work on an online text game and am looking at ways to tell if two accounts are being run by the same person. One thing I think would be helpful would be comparing the times that the accounts are active. I know there are ways to make better graphs, but for now, I am trying to start simple.

I have a df of the logs. One of the columns is a 'time' column. Example '15:27:33'

At first, I tried to make a bar chart to count the number of activities that happened every 15 mins.

```
timedf = df.filter(['time'])
timedf.set_index('time', drop=False, inplace=True)
timedf.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15Min')).count().plot(kind='bar')
```

But I got the error: **TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'**

I tried making it with DateTime instead and it plotted but since this df spans 60 days it was unreadable.
I am just looking to plot the number of logs a user has during each 15 min window of a 24 hour day.
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try convert the data type of the 'time' column to a DatetimeIndex data type so you can perform such operations

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

Comment: Wow. It was that simple. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. If it work will be good if you select the answer, Thank you